# How to translate Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to translate below text in payment module (impossible translate via magento translate in backend):
[image]

I have found translation file in module:

https://github.com/dotpay/magento2-payment/blob/master/i18n/pl_PL.csv

and have added some fields:

- Pay using Masterpass,"Zapłać kartą Masterpass"
- Pay using BLIK,"Zapłać BLIK"
- Pay using Paypal,"Zapłać przez PayPal"
- Pay via Dotpay,"Zapłać przez DotPay"

After FTP uploaded  file, website not loaded:

```
{"0":"Unable to serialize value.","1":"#0 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Translate.php(501): Magento\\Framework\\Serialize\\Serializer\\Json->serialize(Array)\n#1 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Translate.php(211): Magento\\Framework\\Translate->_saveCache()\n#2 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Area.php(244): Magento\\Framework\\Translate->loadData('frontend', false)\n#3 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Area.php(215): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Area->_initTranslate()\n#4 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Area.php(142): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Area->_loadPart('translate')\n#5 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/DesignLoader.php(55): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Area->load('translate')\n#6 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Design.php(48): Magento\\Framework\\View\\DesignLoader->load()\n#7 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Design->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\\Checkout\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#8 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Checkout\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#9 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Checkout\/Controller\/Index\/Index\/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\\Checkout\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#10 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php(55): Magento\\Checkout\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#11 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#12 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#13 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-store\/App\/FrontController\/Plugin\/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#14 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\Store\\App\\FrontController\\Plugin\\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#15 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#16 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#17 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#18 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#19 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#20 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#21 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#22 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mysite.com\/public_html\/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#23 {main}","url":"\/checkout\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Anyone know how to translate correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

1/ Putting all fields into quotation, i.e. `"Pay using Masterpass","Zapłać kartą Masterpass"`

2/ Encode the file into UTF-8 ( Notepad++ is recommended )

Comment: Okay I check this solution and then let you know and accept your answear. thanks.